# Blacklisted number still able to call me under Marshmallow

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow

Can someone explain me following situation:

[image]

How can a blacklisted phone number appear in my incoming calls log which clearly proves that it was calling me?

I have added this particular number to my blacklist (which is confirmed by having `Remove...` instead of `Add...` option in long-press context menu) and yet I'm still receiving calls from this number.

Is this a bug in Marshmallow of am I missing something obvious about blacklisting numbers feature in Android?